# Inner product - Continuous Functions on [-1,1] $ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, vector-spaces, inner-products

$V$ is the vector space of continuous functions $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1f(x)g(x)(1-x^2)dx$

Let $p(x) = 1, q(x)=x$ be elements of $V$

Find $||p||, ||q||$

Answer:

$||p||^2=\int_{-1}^1 1(1−x^2)dx=\int_{-1}^1(1−x^2)dx=[x−\frac{x^3}{3}]^1_{−1}=\frac{4}{3}$. Hence, $||p||=\sqrt{||p||^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}$

Similarly, $||q||^2=\int_{-1}^1 x^2(1−x^2)dx=\int_{-1}^1(x^2-x^5)dx=[\frac{x^3}{3}−\frac{x^5}{5}]^1_{−1}=\frac{4}{15}$. Hence, $||q||=\sqrt{||q||^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4}{15}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt15}$

Then to find the angle between p and q, we use $\theta = cos^{-1}\frac{\langle p,q \rangle}{||p||||q||}$

Then, $\langle p,q \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)(1-x^2)dx = \int_{-1}^1 x(1-x^2)dx = [\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}]^1_{-1} = 0$

Giving $cos^{-1}= \frac{0}{\frac{4}{\sqrt3 \sqrt15}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ radians.

Comment: **Hint** $$\|p\|^2:=\left<p,p\right>=\int_{-1}^1 p(x)^2(1-x^2)\,\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: That image is not a representation of the inner product.

Comment: Thanks, so then $||p||^2=\int_{-1}^1 1(1-x^2)dx = \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)dx = [x-\frac{x^3}{3}]^1_{-1} = \frac{4}{3}.$ Hence, $||p|| = \sqrt{||p||^2} = \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt3}$

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There was originally a question, but I have now edited the post based on the hints given in the comments, to show how I have now answered the question / if my understanding is still incorrect people can assist further

Comment: @JamesBurton It looks correct to me. Just an advice....when you see the integral of an odd function form $-a$ to $a$ , you can directly say it is $0$ without computing it. It would save your time from calculation

Comment: @JamesBurton As you can see, this causes confusion, so I recommend saying that in your question